# How to create an object from another class, and push it into the state array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I'm currently working on a React application, where I two classes - let's call them class App and class Container. Basically, class App has a state array, and I want to have many Container objects in this array.

```
class Container extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return(
          <img src= {this.props.url} />
       );
    }
}



class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            url: ""
            data: []
        }
    }


    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //I WANT TO BE ABLE TO MAKE A NEW CONTAINER, AND PASS THE URL AS PROPS.
        // THEN, I WANT TO ADD THAT CONTAINER TO THE ARRAY.     

        this.setState({
            data: url = this.state.url, id = 'a'
        });
    }


    render(){
        return (
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="url">url:</label>
                    <input
                        type = "text"
                        name = "url"
                        value = {this.state.url}
                        onChange = {this.handleChange}
                    />
           </form>

        )
    }
}
```

In the function handleSubmit() above, I want to add a new container containing the props URL to the array. How would I do this?

Comment: Don't store entire components in the state, only the data needed to render them. Also, if they can create multiple containers with different URLs, then you'll need to store 2 things in the array: the URL they submitted, and preferably a unique identifier to ID that container. So on submission you can have something like `this.setState({ containers: [...this.state.containers, {url: this.state.url, id: "some random ID"}] })`

Comment: Ok, I will edit my solution and let you know in a couple minutes.

Comment: Does this make more sense?

Comment: don't try and directly mutate the state in React, you need to use `this.setState` to change it. Also, `.concat` doesn't actually change the array, it returns a new one, so your code doesn't actually do anything. Use `this.setState` and don't edit state values directly

Comment: Got it. Let me modify once more.

Comment: Would this be correct?

Comment: that's not quite right, you need to *append* the object to the existing array, like I did in my code sample in the comment above. Might want to have a review of object/array syntax in JS, as well as how to update state in React

Comment: Got it, thank you. I'm a complete beginner in React as well, so I apologize for my incompetence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. don't mutate the state
2. you just need `url` in the state, not the whole container
3. use `setState` to modify the state
4. consider using spread operator (`...`) for concatenation
5. I don't see `handleChange` in your code

```js
    class Container extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <img src={this.props.url} />;
      }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          url: "",
          containers: []
        };
      }

      handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
          url: e.target.value
        });
      };

      handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.url) {
          this.setState({
            containers: [...this.state.containers, this.state.url],
            url: ""
          });
        }
      };

      render() {
        const { url, containers } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="url">url:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="url"
                value={url}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <button>submit</button>
            </form>

            <h2>Containers:</h2>
            <div>
              {!containers.length && <i>no urls added</i>}
              {containers.map((_url, i) => (
                <Container key={i} url={_url} />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Working Example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g72uej